# Eloquent model relationship returning as null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel model

```
class Project extends Eloquent {

    public static $timestamps = true;

    public $includes = array('members','members.memberdata');

    public function tasks() {

        return $this->has_many('Usertask','project_id');
    }

    public function members() {

        return $this->has_many('Projectmember','project_id');
    }
}
```

and a related models

```
class Projectmember extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = "project_members";
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function project() {

        return $this->belongs_to('Project');
    }

    public function memberdata() {

        return $this->has_one('Usermetadata','user_id');
    }
}

class Usermetadata extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = "users_metadata";

    public function user() {

        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }

    public function member() {

        return $this->belongs_to('Projectmember','user_id');
    }
}
```

When i attempt to retrieve a single project model like so

```
 $project = Project::find($id);

 return Response::eloquent($project);
```

my json output looks like this

```
{"id":1,"user_id":1,"name":"UberWork","description":"Web based project management \/ task management app","target_date":"2013-11-15 00:00:00","budget":null,"status":0,"created_at":"2013-04-16 20:13:59","updated_at":"2013-04-16 20:13:59","members":[{"id":1,"project_id":1,"user_id":1,"created_at":"2013-04-16 20:13:59","updated_at":"2013-04-16 20:13:59","memberdata":{"user_id":1,"first_name":"Tamarakuro","last_name":"Foh","photo":"","company_name":null,"phone":null,"package":"free","subscription_start":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","subscription_end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","api_key":"12b14a7d3ca48c53bb5b1a88fa3eca3b"}},{"id":3,"project_id":1,"user_id":3,"created_at":"2013-04-16 20:13:59","updated_at":"2013-04-16 20:13:59","memberdata":{"user_id":3,"first_name":"Ebere","last_name":"Uche","photo":"","company_name":"Chronotech Labs","phone":null,"package":"free","subscription_start":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","subscription_end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","api_key":"ab446bd9ffbb898e818a892c7401e0f6"}},{"id":4,"project_id":1,"user_id":2,"created_at":"2013-04-17 08:13:00","updated_at":"2013-04-17 08:13:00","memberdata":null}]}
```

My database look like this;

Users

- id
- email
- password
- ip_address
- active
- ...

users_metadata

- id
- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- profile_photo
- ...

Projects

- id
- user_id
- name
- description
- status
- ...

project_members

- id
- project_id
- user_id

My question is why is the last member of the project having its memberdata as "null", while the others are not null. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that there is a matching record for your last member in the memberdata table? Your last member's `id` and `user_id` do not match, I don't know if this is significant, but the relationship will be matching `id` to the other table's `user_id`?

Comment: Yes there is a matching record on the users_metadata table

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your database design?  What does `user_id` refer to everywhere?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the database design

Comment: The problem is because you want `project_members.user_id = users_metadata.user_id`, but relationships always use the `id` of one table and the fk (`user_id`) on the other table.  This works for most of your data because the `project_members.id` and `project_members.user_id` are the same; it breaks when they're not (your last project member).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships in Eloquent always link a primary key (pk) with a foreign key (fk).  However, you're trying to base a relationship on two foreign keys, skipping out a relationship.  The only Eloquent solution is to include the extra relationship step.  Here are some models (I've ommited the relationships we don't need for this example)...

```
class Project extends Eloquent {

    public static $timestamps = true;

    public $includes = array('members','members.user', 'members.user.metadata');

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Projectmember','project_id');
    }
}

class Projectmember extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = "project_members";
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {

    public static $timestamps = true;

    public $hidden = array('password', 'ip_address');

    public function metadata()
    {
        return $this->has_one('Usermetadata');
    }

}

class Usermetadata extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = "users_metadata";

    public function user() {

        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }

}
```

I can see why you'd want to skip the relationship, but sadly it's not possible with relationships.